# Why doesn't works CreateFile in QT and How can I put it as QLocalSocket or similar

Tags: qt

I have this code running in my old developer c++ borland editor:

```
char address[30];
sprintf(address,"\\\\SERVER_NAME\\EXAMPLE\\ROUTE");
Handle pipe=CreateFile((LPTSTR) &address,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);
```

It works in borland, but when i put the same code in Qt, not work. I don't understand why, pipe returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE in qt.

My goal is that it works in qt and use the class QLocalSocket or another that do the same.

I tried:

```
QLocalSocket * socket = new QLocalSocket(this);
connect(socket, QOverload<QLocalSocket::LocalSocketError>::of(&QLocalSocket::error),this, &Conexion::displayError);
socket->connectToServer("\\\\SERVER_NAME\\EXAMPLE\\ROUTE");
```

But it returns: QLocalSocket::ServerNotFoundError

Thanks you very much, 
Roberto

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious reason your first code sample should work with Borland and not with Qt as this is pure Win32 code.

If you want to find out why it does not work, you have to call `GetLastError()` just after `CreateFile()` fails to retrieve useful information from Windows.

For `QLocalSocket`, you need to have a `QLocalServer` [listening](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html#listen) before you attempt to connect with `QLocalSocket`.